# How to write a RSpec controller macro that can accept arguments defined by let or in a before block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macros, controller

I use Rails 3 and RSpec 2.6.0.

Not sure if that's possible, but here is what I would like to do:

```
describe UsersController do
  let(:user) { Fabricate :user }
  describe "GET /user/:id" do
    should_return_401_code_if_user_is_not_confirmed :get, :show, :id => user.id
  end
  describe "PUT /user/:id" do
    should_return_401_code_if_user_is_not_confirmed :put, :update, :id => user.id
  end
end
```

I tried to implement the macro like this:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def should_return_401_code_if_user_is_not_confirmed(verb, action, params = {})
    it "returns a 401 code if the user is not an admin" do
      send verb, action, params
      response.code.should == "401"
    end
  end
end
```

But when running those specs I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'user'`. I tried to switch to a @user variable defined in a before block, but it does not work either. I suspect it's because I'm not in a example block.

Is it possible to pass to a controller macro arguments defined by let or in a before block?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to consider refactoring the test. It's not a good idea to have two conditions in your test--the presence of the 'if' is a test smell. Are you testing whether the user is confirmed, or just whether the appropriate code is returned? If it's the latter *set* the confirmation rather than check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From reading through [this thread](http://cl.ly/2X0z1q0a3r3B2q2B1U0W) on the rspec-users listserve, it appears the answer is no.  The issue is that your let/before vars aren't being initialized until the `it` block in the body of your macro, so you can't reference them as parameters to the macro call.

I'm trying to do essentially the same thing in a site I'm working on.  The solution I'm going with is to call the macro method with a block that will return the params hash you want, and then use `instance_eval` in the macro body to evaluate the block using the macro's scope.

```
#spec
...
describe "GET /user/:id" do
  should_return_401_code_if_user_is_not_confirmed :get, :show { {:id => user.id} }
end

#macro
...
def should_return_401_code_if_user_is_not_confirmed(verb, action, &params_block)
  it "returns a 401 code if the user is not an admin" do
    params = instance_eval &params_block
    send verb, action, params
...
```